# How to avoid EMFILE, open error?

Tags: node.js

I get the error:

```
EMFILE, open <filename>
```

I don't think this is the same as the situation when there are too many files open.

When I run `ulimit`, the output is: `unlimited` , so I don't think that is the problem.
I create many subdirectories, and when the subdirectories are creates, I call `fs.exists` to check that the directory actually exists before doing `fs.writeFile`

What is the problem ?

EDIT: ulimit -n outputs 1024

Comment: `ulimit` with no option displays the maximum output *size* . For number of opens, use `ulimit -n`, or `ulimit -a` and look at the line for `-n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use writeFile or even appendFile, both of them open file to each append.

Using a stream is far better. You can manage your own file handle and close it when you want, or not :)

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("append.txt", {flags:'a'});
stream.write("data");
stream.end;
```

Comment: but what is the problem ?

Comment: Appendfile opens and closes file for each line it adds, so when you have too many lines, node opens in same time more files descriptor than allowed by system. Then he throws an error and doesn't write anymore.  If you use a simple write stream, aka file handle, you can write what you want without any problem, because you open file only one time. See fs createWritestream.

Answer (score 2):

You should try graceful-fs: https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs

As the description says, it Queues up open and readdir calls, and retries them once something closes if there is an EMFILE error from too many file descriptors.

Here's a nice explanation: http://blog.izs.me/post/56827866110/wtf-is-emfile-and-why-does-it-happen-to-me

Comment: I can't use graceful, because the problem is that there are too many descriptors open for writing. Graceful only queues open and readdir calls.